# Regex Expression Issue with commit Message

Tags: regex, git

Need this type of Commit Message

```
TaskId : 123456 - commit message
TaskId: 123456 - commit message
TaskId:123456 - commit message
TaskId:123456- commit message
TaskIds : 123456**,123456** ( This Can be multiple times with space without space ) - commit message
TaskIds : 123456**and 123456** ( This Can be multiple times with space without space ) - commit message
Task id - 1233443:commit message
```

I have tried this regex but few things are missing

```
[Tt][Aa][Ss][Kk][Ss]?\s*(?:[Ii][Dd])?\s*[: \s-]?(\s*(?:,|and)?\s*\d+)?\s*(?:\s*)
```

Expected output is :

```
$1 = (TaskId:123456,123456) In the commit message on Bitbucket This should be a Link to my custom task system

For Ex:
**https://abc.xyz.com?taskid=$1**
```

Comment: The "ex" in "regex" already means "expression" (it's an abbreviation of "regular expression").

Comment: "Tried" how, using what tool(s), to achieve which result?

Comment: On Bitbucket i need link on my commit message that what ever digits find in commit message it should supposed to be an link for my customize task System

Comment: Not sure what you need. Could you provide expected output for each input you specified?

Answer (score 2):

Removing the comments from the text, then I assume what you want to match is: (and similar variants)

```
TaskId : 123456 - commit message
TaskId: 123456 - commit message
TaskId:123456 - commit message
TaskId:123456- commit message
TaskIds : 123456, 123456 - commit message
TaskIds : 123456 and 123456 - commit message
Task id - 1233443:commit message
```

Instead of `[Tt][Aa][Ss][Kk][Ss]?` then you could also use the insensitive flag and change that part to `tasks?`

If you want to limit `(\s*(?:,|and)?\s*\d+)*` to only accept a single `,`/`and`, then you can flip it around, i.e. match `\d+` and then zero-to-many `", number"`. In short `(?:(\d+)(?:\s*(?:,|and)\s*(\d+))*)`.

The final pattern could look something like this:

```regex
^task(?:\s*ids?)\s*[:-]\s*(?:(\d+)(?:\s*(?:,|and)\s*(\d+))*)\s*[:-]\s*(.*)$
```

[**Demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/aKjRso/1)

Comment: It is not working 
On Bitbucket > repository Settings > link > Add link > custom link => https://.abc.xyx.com?taskId = 123456,152365

I need this type of customization

Comment: I don't follow the connection between a regex and a "custom link", I don't use Bitbucket. Feel free to update your question with the additional information, that is required to understand the context of your question.

Comment: Added few more things

Comment: It is working properly But Bitbucket have some Bug on there link system that's why it is not working over there